# Read GRPC headers

Tags: c#, grpc

I'm sending data via GRPC to, let's call it, `IntegrationApi`, calling a method `Foo`. I need to read header values from the response (the API I'm communicating with sends rate-limiting headers).

I'm using https://www.nuget.org/packages/Grpc.Core/

```cs
var metaData = new Metadata();
metadata.Add(new Metadata.Entry("Authorization", $"Bearer {apiKey}"));
var channel = new Channel("url to endpoint", new SslCredentials());
var client = new IntegrationApi(channel);

var callOptions = new CallOptions()
.WithHeaders(metadata)
.WithDeadline(DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(15))
.WithWaitForReady(false);

var response = client.Foo(req, options);
```

but the `response` only gives me the properties based on the `Foo.proto` file.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the synchronous version of "Foo" method, and that one uses a simplified version of the API (=only allows access to the response and throws RpcExceptions in case of an error).

If you call the asynchronous version of the same method ("FooAsync"), you'll get back a call object that can access all the call details (such as response headers).

https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/044a8e29df4c5c2716c7e8250c6b2585e1c425ff/src/csharp/Grpc.Core.Api/AsyncUnaryCall.cs#L73

Comment: true, after changing it to FooAsync I was able to access the right headers.